# synaptic tries to uninstall so many packages when trying to install openssh-server

Tags: apt, package-management, ssh

I've been tyring to get openssh-server through `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`, but when I ran it I got the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:6.6p1-2ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried using synaptic to install things from where, but when trying to install it, I was presented with a dialog box saying that many packages are going "to be removed", the likes of audacity, clang, clementine, g++, glmark2.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Remove these packages, as you might not have it installed from official repo. Use command below to remove it but make sure no more packages are uninstalled, like half of the system!

> sudo apt-get remove openssh-server openssh-client

Then, update you repository info with

> sudo apt-get update

And finally install needed packages with

> sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client

If you get some unexpected results, post it here.
IF it doesn't help (3 commands above), then you might have something broken on your system due to installing/adding different software repositories and system is not unable to resolve dependencies. In that case, you should post here file content of  **/etc/apt/sources.list**  and all files from folder **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/**